# Slow Post request in React Native

Tags: react-native, fetch, apisauce

I am making a `post` request in `react-native` using `apisauce`, but the request is too slow. The request takes around `1000ms` in `Postman`, but is slower in `react-native`. How can I optimize this?

My sample response `data` is like

```
[
    {
      "email": "abc@gmail.com",
      "id": 2753,
      "phone_number": "",
      "user_name": "New client"
    },
    {
      "email": "cda@gmail.com",
      "id": 2754,
      "phone_number": "",
      "user_name": "New client"
    },
    {
      "email": "dsa@gmail.com",
      "id": 8868,
      "phone_number": "",
      "user_name": "Slow"
    }
  ]
```

And the program for post request is:

```
    const setConfigHeader = () =>
        api.setHeader(
          'Authorization',
          getState().login.data.access_token
            ? `Bearer ${getState().login.data.access_token}`
            : null,
        );
    
    const getAddressBookData = data =>
        api.post(globalConstants.user_address_book, data, setConfigHeader());
```

Comment: The question is not clear. You have mentioned that its taking 1000ms on postman. Are you saying that its taking longer on react-native or its taking longer on postman?

Comment: Please share your code of `post`.

Comment: @SagarShakya it's taking longer on react-native. @Shan Alam I have added the code for `post`